# Rails 2.3.5: routes names for members action to be different from the action name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a rails 2.3.5 application where an action acb is changed to pqr and modified so that it works only for "get" method.

To achive this I have used resource route with options like

`map.resources :controller, :member => {:pqr => :get}`

The original view file has acb_controller_path link in many places. If I change the path in view file as pqr_controller_path it works fine.

Is there a way I can refer acb_controller_path to controller/:id/pqr ?

Answer (score 1):

You're better off changing the view paths to point to your new route, and I think I'm misunderstanding your question a little but depending which way you're trying to do it, you can try something like this I guess?

```
map.acb_controller '/controller/:id/pqr', :controller => "controller", :action => "pqr"
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but for me I have 10 methods (that will work on all HTTP request methods) in older application and those are being changed to say around 25 based on the HTTP request methods.